# Norm-Square of $1−i+2e^{iπ/4}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Why is $\left|1 - i + 2e^{i \pi/4}\right|^2 = 6$?

I am getting:

\begin{align}
\left|1 - i + 2e^{i \pi/4}\right|^2 &= (1 - i + 2e^{i \pi/4})(1 + i + 2e^{-i \pi/4})\\&= 1 + i + 2e^{-i \pi /4} - i + 1 - 2ie^{-i \pi /4} + 2e^{i \pi /4} + 2ie^{i \pi /4} + 4 \\
&= 6 + 2(e^{i \pi /4} + e^{-i \pi /4})\\&= 6 + 4\cos(\pi/4)\\&= 6 + 2\sqrt{2}
\end{align}

However, my textbook and Wolfram Alpha agrees that it is 6 instead. Did I miss an identity?

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=norm-square+of+%281+%2B+2e%5E%28i+pi%2F4%29+-+i%29

Comment: What about your $2i(e^{i\pi/4}-e^{-i\pi/4})$ term?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your $2i(e^{i\pi/4}-e^{-i\pi/4})$ term indeed went poof. Another route to calculate this would be to note that $e^{i\pi/4}=\cos(\pi/4)+i\sin(\pi/4)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ so that $1-i+2e^{i\pi/4}=(1+\sqrt{2})+i(\sqrt{2}-1)$. Then using that $|a+bi|^2=a^2+b^2$, we have $|1-i+2e^{i\pi/4}|^2=(1+\sqrt{2})^2+(\sqrt{2}-1)^2=6$.